# Set Apache's vhosts with a sub-domain automatically

Tags: domain-name-system, virtualhost, apache-2.4, bind, wildcard

I'm posting here, because I want to configure apache vhosts automatically, like a.mydomain.com , b.mydomain.com ,etc ... but It doesn't work.

I've already setting up a DNS Wilcard record like ( *   3600   IN    A  1.2.3.4 ).

and setting up my appache like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/%1
    UseCanonicalName Off


    <Directory /var/www/vhosts>
            DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # Custom Errors
    ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404/index.html

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond /var/www/vhosts/%1 -d

    RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =*.mydomain.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.com
```

This is working :

When I'm typing mydomain.com/index.html , I show the good content .

This doesn't work :

When I'm typing a.mydomain.com or something.mydomain.com , I show the same content but normally, It will must show other content . And if I don't type /index.html, I got " Forbidden" .

Can you help me ?

Comment: You have to clarify at which point you need help..what works, what doesn't, etc. Be verbose, and people will be able to support you.